# How to identify the cell the Function is in?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

In Column D of my table I have a custom Function whose variables are in columns A and B:

```
=MyFunction([ColumnA],[ColumnB])
```

I realize now that the function also needs to capture the string that's in Column C. I could add it as another variable:

```
=MyFunction([ColumnA],[ColumnB],[ColumnC])
```

...but I'm hoping I can do so without adding the variable.

It would be great if the function could identify the cell it was in, kind of like ActiveCell:

```
Public Function(VarA, VarB)
  ColumnCtext = ThisCell.Offset(0,-1).value
End Function
```

...where, for each row in Column D, "ThisCell" returns -- well, the cell in question.

Is that possible?

Comment: `Application.Caller`, but it will generate a circular reference if you use its `.Value` property.  (It should be safe to use `Application.Caller.Offset(0, -1).Value` though.)

Comment: And another warning, unless you make the function `Volatile`, a change to the value in column C will not force a recalc of the function in column D - which is why it would be much, much better to add the range to the parameters (maybe even passing a single range parameter that is `A2:C2`?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Application.Caller` can be used to identify the cell from which the function was called.

Some warnings:

1. If you try to use `Application.Caller.Value` you will get a circular reference.  Using the `Caller` to get another cell's value, e.g. `Application.Caller.Offset(0, -1).Value` will be OK.
2. Because you don't intend to pass the cell whose value is being used in the function as a parameter, any changes to that cell will **not** cause a recalculation of your function unless you mark your function as being `Volatile`.  (And doing that means your function will be called any time **any** cell is changed.)